# No Transparency in Mac Virtual Machine

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, vmware-player

I am running Windows 8.1 natively with Mac OSX El Capitan running via VMWare Player 12 and I have noticed there is no transparency. This might have something to do with the VM having only 128mb of Graphics Ram. If that is the issue how can I enable transparency because I really like the slight blur everything has.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you possibly include a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm being dumb here, but I think you do know that Aero blur/transparency went away with Windows 8? Nothing is transparent in Windows 8.1, save the taskbar.

Answer (score -1):

you could try downloading the video driver for your mac. Find out what cpu it has got and if it has a graphics card. If it doesn't have a graphics card then you should go onto intel's driver website. insert the type of cpu you have got then you should be able to install it in win 8.1 If you have a graphics card, find out the name of that then look up the driver for it
Also you should up your video memory/

Comment: I have windows 8 running a virtual machine with Mac OSX on it.

Comment: And how can I up my video memory? Not too sure how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure if VMWare player has the video memory setting, and some quick searching isn't turning anything up. I know in Workstation, you can ramp up a slider that reserves more and more of the host's VRAM for the machine. Check in the VM display settings for that one. Also, there's no such thing as a downloadable video driver for mac in most cases, since they all come with the OS. @Lachlan